# How do I add content and autoplay/loop Vimeo videos in Colorbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox for a college assessment. Basically there is a 200 x 200px grid on my site and each square is a different entry (.GIF). When you click on an entry a colorbox opens with a Vimeo link to that GIF in a higher resolution (800 x 800px). I have information such as Name, Country, URL and Description that I want to display next to the embedded Vimeo video how i'm not sure how to do that. I would also like to somehow autoplay and loop the Vimeo video.

Here is what I have so far: http://dev.gridflux.net/

As you can see when you click on an entry the Colorbox opens, however the background doesn't dim, the video doesnt autoplay (let alone loop) and I can only display the title underneath.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks, James.

Answer (score 0):

To autoplay, go into your vimeo settings and you can pick it to autoplay through that (it also gives you an embed code if you prefer it that way). For looping, vimeo itself doesn't allow it but I too am looking for a looped vimeo, so let me know if you find it!